# Show whether a post is plus or minus with Wp-Postratings

Tags: plugins, plugin-wp-postratings

Im using WP-Postratings to show thumbs up or down for posts and I want to show on the homepage  in post excerpts whether a post in in the plus or minus. If it's in the plus I want to show a custom image but if the negative I want to show a different image. Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured this out. The ratings score is stored as a custom field so I created and if statements to check whether the score was less, equal, or greater than 0 and then I can show something accordingly. Here's how I set it up.

```
<?php 
  $ratings_score = get_post_meta($post->ID,'ratings_score',true); 
  if ($ratings_score < 0 ) {
      echo '<span>Plus</span>'; 
      } elseif ($ratings_score > 0 ) {
      echo '<span>Minus</span>';
      } else {
      echo '<span>Even</span>';
      }
 ?>
```